# Remove final comma from string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to build a comma-delimited string from an array.

```
For i=0 to ubound(arr)
    str+= arr(i) & ","
Next i
```

The trouble is that I end up with an extra comma at the end.

My current method for removing the comma is:

```
If str<>"" then
    Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
End if
```

But it seems pretty untidy, and non-generic. I have to do this so often, it's become a pain. Anyone got a better one?

Comment: The real answer is `String.Join`, but to remove one or more specific characters from the end of a string look at [`String.TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `String.Join`. Refer to the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx

**Sample code:**

```
Dim values() As Object = {"Cobb", 4189, 11434, .366 }
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", values))
' The example displays the following output:
'      Cobb,4189,11434,0.366
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumes that you have at least one item in the array:

```
str += arr(0)
For i=1 to ubound(arr)
    str+= "," & arr(i)
Next i
```